# User groups and permissions

Tags: django, django-permissions

I need to implement user rights for user groups (pretty similar to facebook groups). For example, each group can have members with rights like: can_post, can_delete, can_ban, etc. Of course, one user can be a member of many groups and group can have many different users with different rights.

What models I need for this functionality?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Django has a built in groups system. Whenever you have a question like this, I recommend [searching the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/search/?q=groups&release=1), which are extensive, helpful, and well written.

So long as you are using the `django.contrib.auth` app, you have access to groups. You can then assign permissions to those groups.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myapp', model='BlogPost')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_publish',
                                       name='Can Publish Posts',
                                       content_type=content_type)
user = User.objects.get(username='duke_nukem')
group = Group.objects.get(name='wizard')
group.permissions.add(permission)
user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: in which file do you usually put this piece of code?

Comment: The code above creates records, so it's the sort of thing you'd run from within the shell. If you wanted to distribute your app or deploy it, you'd need to set it up so that this initial data was saved. I believe you can also modify them within the admin on the website.

Comment: same thing I did with mine, did that on shell or admin and then generated a fixture to load on future instances of the application. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yeah, but how do you deploy this? Fixtures have been depreciated :-?

Comment: According to the current documentation, fixtures seem to still be acceptable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/initial-data/ In fact, it appears the deprecation notice was removed. So Django people are not being clear at all what the support actually is.

Comment: Custom permissions can be defined in model's `Meta` class and they'll be automatically created on `manage.py migrate`. More details in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions).

Comment: @JordanReiter, link is dead...

Comment: @nerdoc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/initial-data/ guaranteed working forever.