# Grouping standard user models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have a webapp and all of my users are divided into 2 groups: Teachers and Students. How can I create groups and assign users to groups in order to identify which group a user belongs to in Django? Additionally, can I create views that only certain groups can access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some resources below for you to take a look at:

You can create a two groups, `Teacher` and `Student`. You will then assign permissions to these groups, not the individual users. Therefore, if you part of the teacher group, you get all teacher permissions.

[Django groups docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#groups)

[Medium article for groups](https://medium.com/djangotube/django-roles-groups-and-permissions-introduction-a54d1070544)

[Creating groups - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797593/how-to-create-a-group-permission-in-django)