# How to get rid of group related queries?

Tags: python, django, session, refactoring

I have to refactor code which is like:

*views.py*

```
def some_method(request):
    customers = list()
    if request.session['group'] == "group1":
        foo = foo.objects.filter(blue=True)
    else:
        foo = foo.objects.all()
```

I have a lot of if else statements that I want to reduce using django builtin permissions, auth functionality. Any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [User groups and permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393726/user-groups-and-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read: [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator), and specialy the section: [The permission_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator).

There you will find that you could refactor your function like this:

```
@permission_required('some.permission.only.group1.has')
def some_method(request):
    customers = list()
    foo = foo.objects.filter(blue=True)
```

For the case the user isn't in the `group1` should exist another view. The example you posted don't really ilustrates the need for having a view for each case, but believe me it will make your life easier.

**A Tip:** In templates you can restrict what the user sees using permissions as well. You might manage permissions even before the view get called.

```
{% if perms.app_label.can_do_something %}
<form here>
{% endif %}
```

> The currently logged-in user's permissions are stored in the template variable {{ perms }}

References: [Check permission inside a template in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469590/check-permission-inside-a-template-in-django)