# DIfferent user levels in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-authentication

I am using Django's auth.

I want to distinguish between 3 types of users and present different content for each type of user.

How can I distinguish between these 3 types? Should I add a choice field specifying the type of user or create 3 groups and add the users to the right group?

How can I present different content according to the type of user?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `django.contrib.auth` is primarily suited for authentication and authorization.

What you should do depends on what exactly `type of user` means.

In the typical situation where `type` represents different levels of authorizations the user has, then you should consider using the permission system (or running an existing one, see e.g. [here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/)).

If `type` represents an intrinsic property of the user (like male/female/other), then use a custom user and add a new ChoiceField to it.

If `type` represents something more complex, that potentially will have relations with other models, then I would go for a new model `UserType`.

Answer (score 1):

Create three different classes:

```
class Level1(models.model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Level2(models.model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Level3(models.model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

To check and present different content for each user of different levels in the views:

```
if Level1.objects.filter(memeber=user).count() > 0:
    // present the content you want
else Level2.objects.filter(memeber=user).count() > 0:
    // present the content you want
else Level3.objects.filter(memeber=user).count() > 0:
    // present the content you want
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only assign different permissions to different type of user, go ahead and create an user group
its pretty simple 
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

newgroup = Group.objects.create(name=group_name)

The following answer will also help you setting permissions

[User groups and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393726/user-groups-and-permissions)