# Do something once in django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to create two groups once per project's life. So, I read about [`AppConfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393845)

And I created `core.appconfig.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class RolesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'roles_config'
    verbose_name = 'Roles configuration'
    def create_roles(self):
        driver = Group.objects.create(name='driver')
        manager = Group.objects.create(name='manager')
        driver.save()
        manager.save()
```

And the in `settings.py`: `default_app_config = 'core.appconfig.RolesConfig'`
But when I run server and go to the admin page, there are no groups. Why? When is `AppConfig` called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations):

1. Create an empty migration file with `manage.py makemigrations <app_name> --empty`.
2. Create a function that adds the default values to the database.

```
def create_roles(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
    driver = Group.objects.create(name='driver')
    manager = Group.objects.create(name='manager')
```

3. Add a `RunPython` operation to you migrations:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_roles),
    ]
```

Automatic loading of data fixtures has been [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures) in favour of data migrations.

Comment: add `RunPython` to `__init__.py` or to `0001_initial.py`? And what if I have already migrations directory in that app?

Comment: In the file created by `makemigrations` in step 1. It doesn't matter if you had previous migrations, it will create a new migration that depends on the older migrations. Your `__init__.py` should be empty. Be sure to read through [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), as I might have missed something.

Comment: a question about this: `Group = apps.get_model('myapp', 'Group')`. Group is a python's model, so what app should I write?

Comment: The `app_label` defaults to the last component of the app's name, i.e. the `auth` part of `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: when doing `migrate` next error: `LookupError: No installed app with label 'django.contrib.auth'.
`

Comment: You need the app label (`auth`), not its name (`django.contrib.auth`).

Answer (score 3):

I consider @Leistungsabfall answer to be correct, apart from that: don't do this. App config was not built for this purpose, instead you should create fixtures: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/ .

App config is run every time you run the application so it would not really work.

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Comment: when deploying my site, I guess that `fixtures` won't work on server. Or Am I wrong? I used to use fixtures, my just to load some initial data, and always had to run `loaddata`. But how to do it without writing `loaddata` and it creates two groups automatically?

Comment: You are wrong, fixtures will absolutely work on your server, besides you should only run it once - when you create DB. Also fixtures wont create duplicities as long as you also specify primary key value.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here:

1. Make sure the path to `appconfig.py` is `myapp/appconfig.py`.
2. Make sure that `name` is your Django application name (e.g. `myapp`).
3. Rename `create_roles(self)` to `ready(self)`.
4. In `myapp/__init__.py` (create this file if it doesn't exist) add this line:

   ```
   default_app_config = 'myapp.appconfig.RolesConfig'
   ```
5. Remove `driver.save()` and `manager.save()`, they are redundant because `create()` already does save the objects in the database.

(Replace `myapp` with your Django application name.)

Comment: In this `default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.RolesConfig'` maybe `'myapp.appconfig.RolesConfig'`?

Comment: You're right. `'myapp.apps.RolesConfig'` has to be `'myapp.appconfig.RolesConfig'`. I've edited the answer.