# Permissions on my Model for Django

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

I have a model called `Logs`:

```
class Logs(models.Model):
    entry = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Some Users can administer logs, others edit and the rest only view. **How would you handle such permissions in Django?**

I was thinking of adding a new `many-to-many` field, one for admins the other for editors, then on the save function check which user is in what group.

However, this seems static and bad, can I somehow use Django's built in permissions? What other solutions, packages are there, what is the best approach to this problem?

I have seen you can create custom permissions in Django i.e.

```
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_publish',
                                       name='Can Publish Logs',
                                       content_type=content_type)
```

But how on `Logs` would I check the permissions, would this be done in the `Save()` method.

Comment: yes, just set up user Groups and use the Django permissions system https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Comment: how to check the permissions is a bit further down that docs page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator

Comment: @Anentropic can you apply the decorators for this to the Django Rest Framework i.e. on the view there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking for permissions functionality which is implemented for you in [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/).

In particular you would like to control who can edit a model, which is included in the [default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) of django. You can also implement [custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions) if you need to.

You would check these privileges on the views and django.contrib.auth provides the `permission_required` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator). Which does what you require.

You do not need to reimplement the many to many field for editors admins and users either. You can use django.contrib.auth `Group` to add your users to the respective group and then assign permissions to the groups:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from api.models import Logs
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='new_group')
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Logs)

permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_clean_logs',
                                   name='Can clean logs',
                                   content_type=ct)
new_group.permissions.add(permission)
```

Check [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) for more fine-grained control and object-level permissions.

[django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) provides a hook for [permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) and provides a integration of django model permissions.

The following answer can also be helpful:

[User Groups and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393726/user-groups-and-permissions)

Comment: +1 for Django-guardian.  Though you may not need another dependency for one class and can implement permissions yourself.